# Order by After Where clause not working in MySQLi PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

Order By After Where is not returning results below is the code and screenshot of not running code.

```
SELECT * from `SalesMessages` where `ThreadId`= ? ORDER BY `id` desc Limit 25;
```

However if I remove bind params it works fine.

```
SELECT * from `SalesMessages` where `ThreadId`=63 ORDER BY `id` desc Limit 25;
```

Below is screen shot from mySql

[mysql query and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZNGc.png)

HERE IS HOW I WROTE MYSQLI Code

```
    global $conn;
    $arr = array();
    mysqli_set_charset( $conn, 'utf8'); // ALREADY TRIED COMMENTING THIS LINE
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $ThreadId);
    try {
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                ..SOME CODE..
            }
            if (count($arr) > 0)
                return $arr;
        } else {
            throw "QueryError";
        }
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }
}
```

Here is the structure of Table

[DATA BASE STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuGFe.png)

I am expecting results from mysql in PHP code as array.

Comment: Check `$stmt->get_warnings();`. Enable General Log and look at the text of the statement which is received by MySQL.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0):

It was connection Error guys Which was using another database which does not had records. Everything else is working fine now. Actually the table in connected database had no record in required table.